# What number continues this sequence

Tags: number-sequence

I just came up with this one, what is the value of N in this sequence

7,5,1,2,4,8,N?

Comment: Is "N?" the blank you want filled, or is the N part of the sequence?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan N is the value, I've updated the question to clarify this. Unfortunately I couldn't post the question without a sentence ending punctuation mark

Comment: OK, that's clearer. And would you like to indicate whether the sequence continues on after the number N or steps there, and; whether it continues backwards before the 7 or starts there? (You might prefer not to, of course.)

Comment: A word of warning: this sort of question often turns out to have quite a lot of somewhat-plausible answers and may get closed as "too broad" if so...

Comment: inspired by sandbox,i think all of these sequence puzzle should go through [oeis](https://oeis.org/)

Comment: I'd be all in favour of closing number-sequence puzzles whose solutions are found in OEIS.

Comment: I agree with you @GarethMcCaughan

Comment: Thanks, I'll check OEIS before posting again. Are there any guidelines for good/undesirable questions on the site?

Comment: @Steve In the [help center](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you can read about what is on topic. That page also has several links at the bottom that give more information on what makes a good puzzle for this site.

Answer (score 6):

N is

> 7

because

> each number is the previous number times 2, mod 9.

Comment: Correct answer!

Comment: oeis says too..